# Need to create a duplicate table in a separate schema automatically whenever a new table is being created

Tags: stored-procedures, trigger, db2, table, ddl-trigger

Whenever a new table is being created in Schema 'A', I need the table to be duplicated in the Schema 'B'. This should happen automatically. I have searched for trigger concept but it wont work on DDL statements like 'CREATE' or 'ALTER' statements. How do I achieve this without triggers? Please help me.

Comment: The solution could be to use Db2 ATS (or any other scheduler) and undocumented `SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL` routine, which may be called for every table existing in your schema A and not existing in schema B with an appropriate schema name modification in DDL generated by this routine.